# How to update remote git repo history without altering remote files

Tags: git, shell, deployment, sh

I'm aware this is likely not best practice, but I am trying to use `git push` as a deployment method for a web project. Our remote repo is hosted on our own server and lives in the same filesystem as our production folder.

My goal is essentially to use `git push` to push our project to the remote repo, where a server tool (plesk) automatically copies the repo to our production folder after a push. This part works fine.

The problem is that I also want to push our compiled CSS, JS and other build artifacts--which are not tracked by git (via the project `.gitignore` file)--along with the repo's tracked files. I want to keep those files untracked and I'd like to try using a process like this (as opposed to a separate deployment tool) because of how fast and simple `git push` is (it'd be ideal if I didn't need to add another tool into the mix).

My attempts so far have led me to write a simple deployment shell script that looks like this:

```sh
# ...

if grunt build-full; then
  # temporarily force add and commit ignored build files/dirs to repo
  git add ${build_files[@]} -f &&
  git commit ${build_files[@]} -m "Add compiled css, js, etc for push deploy"

  # push if successful
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # update remote (just in case)
    git remote update $remote
    
    # push 
    git push $remote $repo -f
    
    # remove temporarily added files, commit removal
    git rm ${build_files[@]} -f --cached &&
    git commit -m "Remove temporary build files" &&
    
    # reset repo to before removal and add commits to remove unneeded commits
    # (while keeping working directory files), push to sync remote 
    git reset HEAD~2 &&
    git push $remote $repo -f
  fi
fi
```

The idea is to add the ignored files temporarily, push them, remove them from the repo while keeping them in the filesystem (via `git rm --cached`), and then sync the remote (via another push) by removing the temporarily-added build files from the repo, but also keeping them in the remote filesystem. Ideally, I'd like to remove the "deploy" commits afterwards (or leave just one at most)--hence the `git reset`--but this is less important.

This seems to work well until the last bit: the final push just removes the build files on the server (even though they're preserved in my local working directory). If I try omitting the last push, the server's filesystem reflects what I'm looking for (build files are still there), but then the remote is ahead of the local (because of the `git reset`--or behind if I remove the reset, too).

Is there a way to push untracked build files (by temporarily adding them or otherwise) and then remove them from tracking again on both local and remote without removing the just-pushed files on the remote filesystem? Or is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to push untracked build files (by temporarily adding them or otherwise) and then remove them from tracking again on both local and remote without removing the just-pushed files on the remote filesystem?

Probably not.  The problem is not, or at least not exactly, in Git, but rather in whatever deployment software you are using.  If you're (ab?)using Git as a deployment system, the scripts you use to turn Git into the deployment system are the problem here: Git is a tool-set, and one must use care which tools one uses in which situations.

Note that locally, you specifically use one particular Git tool in one particular way:

> ```
> git rm ${build_files[@]} -f --cached
> ```

In effect, you'd have to get your deployment system to do this as well (perhaps even doing it literally).  I'm not familiar with Plesk internals to say whether there is a way to get it to do this.

The rest of this answer is optional, but probably useful for your purposes.  In particular, there *is* a different way to deal with this, which will allow you to use Git as your deployment system.  You just have to stop deploying the commits you're deploying today.  Make your to-be-deployed commits slightly differently, and otherwise keep going the way you have been.

#### How to understand what's going on (and what you will do)

Git is really all about *commits*.  Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file—or more precisely but apparently tautological, a snapshot of every file that it holds.  The idea here is that a snapshot is not a delta: it doesn't say *to use this commit, start by getting to the previous commit, then make these changes* but rather *to use this commit, here are your files*.

What this means is that an *untracked file* isn't in the commit.  If file *F* is untracked and you make a new commit, file *F* simply *isn't there*.  The mechanism behind this is Git's *index*, which holds a copy of each file that will go into the *next* commit.  An untracked file is one that is not in the index.  A file that is not in the index can also be ignored, meaning Git should not normally add it *to* the index, and should not whine about its untracked-ness.

When you run (note, I'm dropping the `&&`s for discussion purposes only):

> ```
> git add ${build_files[@]} -f
> ```

this forcibly adds those files, even if they are marked "to be ignored".  Now there *is* a copy of those files in Git's index, so now, if you make a new commit, they will be in that commit.  The next line is of course:

> ```
> git commit ${build_files[@]} -m "Add compiled css, js, etc for push deploy"
> ```

This makes a new commit.  The new commit contains *all* the files that are in Git's index.  Mentioning `${build_files[@]}` on the command line is unnecessary, as the default `git commit` action with files listed on the command line is to use the `--include` option rather than the `--only` option.  The effect is as if you'd run `git add` again on each of those files, just before committing.<sup>1</sup>  So you could just write this as the `git add` you have followed by:

```
git commit -m "Add compiled css, js, etc for push deploy"
```

Either way, this adds a new commit that contains all the previous files *plus* the forcibly-added files.  That's because the index *doesn't change* when you commit:<sup>2</sup> you copy some files into it, and then `git commit` turns the index into a commit, but the index itself remains the same, and now matches the commit you just made.  (Since the commit was made *from* the index, they must match.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are technical differences between `git add F && git commit` and `git commit --include F` in terms of which index file(s) are used and what happens in the unusual case of the commit *failing*, but for a successful commit, the end result is close enough to think of it as a separate add-and-commit.  If you use the `--only` option, as in `git commit --only F`, the situation is considerably more complicated: there are now *three* index files involved.  The `--include` option doesn't create any extra index files.  All commits create a temporary `index.lock`; `--include` uses `index` and `index.lock` in a somewhat different way than `git commit` with neither `--include` nor `--only`, but otherwise is easy to analogize to add-then-commit; but `--only` is tricky.

<sup>2</sup>Again, `git commit --only` is particularly tricky here, as Git does a fancy series of tricks using its three separate index files, and typically winds up changing the main index after a successful commit.

---

#### Commits are numbered, and record two things

Commits have numeric IDs, but these IDs are not sequential: they're hashes.  The hash ID of each commit is unique to that one particular commit.  No other commit will ever have that same hash ID—not just in *this* Git, but in *any* Git this Git ever talks to.  So if you know the hash ID of some commit, you can ask your Git to extract that commit (provided your Git *has* that commit of course).  If your Git is talking to some other Git, both Gits can agree about which commits they have, and which ones they might want.

While a commit stores a snapshot, that's not everything it does.  It also stores some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why—the log message you supplied with `-m` above.  One item in this metadata is specifically for Git itself, and that's the hash ID—the commit number—of the *previous* commit.  This is how history works: the history of a commit is simply its previous commit.

Merge commits are a little bit special, in that they have two (or more) previous commits: the usual first one like any commit is the commit that comes before it, and the second saved hash ID is the ID of the commit that got merged.  Otherwise, a merge commit is just like any other commit: it has a full snapshot of all of its files.

To see what happened in some commit, Git simply extracts *both* commits to a temporary in-memory area.  Git can short circuit a lot of this work because of the internal storage format: files are automatically de-duplicated and it's easy to tell if the two commits just re-used some file.  Having extracted all the files from both (or not bothered for the easy files-are-same cases), Git checks to see which files are the same, and which ones are different, and then *does nothing at all* about the ones that are the same.  For those that are different, Git computes a set of changes that would modify the earlier commit's files to produce the later commit's files.

Since that's how Git *shows* a commit, some people assume that that's how Git *stored* the commit.  But it's not!  The commit is just a snapshot.  Meanwhile, the history—the linkage from each commit to its parent or parents—lets Git show you how the software evolved over time.

#### To use a commit, we must extract it

Files in Git are stored in a compressed and de-duplicated form, frozen for all time—or at least, for as long as any commit in the repository continues to refer to them.  These files literally *can't* be used by most non-Git software.  To work with them, we have Git *extract* them, into a *working tree* or *work-tree*.

When Git extracts a commit—using `git checkout` or, since Git 2.23, `git switch`—Git does so by first filling in its own index.  This means that the index contains all the files *from* that commit, ready to go into a new commit.  Git also copies the files out to your work-tree, wherever that is (usually right where you're working).<sup>3</sup>  Only the files that are *in* that commit are now in the index, but *all* the files that are *in* that commit are now in the index.  Any untracked files that were present in your work-tree before, remain in your work-tree.

If we switch from commit *C1* to commit *C2*, and commit *C1* has some file *F* that commit *C2* specifically *omits*, Git will know to remove *F* from your work-tree.  The reason it knows to remove *F* is that *F* is *also* in Git's index.  If it was in the index, it came out of commit *C1*, so moving from *C1* to *C2* means *remove the file from the index and from your work-tree*.

---

<sup>3</sup>Hosting systems typically have *bare* repositories, which have no work-tree.  You can, however, assign a *temporary* work-tree with `GIT_WORK_TREE` (environment variable) or `--work-tree` (flag), and when you do, the repository becomes temporarily non-bare.  There's still an index even for a bare repository, and if you don't override Git, Git will use the otherwise-unused index while working with this temporary work-tree.

(Even with a non-bare repository, you can, in modern Git, separate your Git directory from your work-tree at creation time with `--separate-git-dir`.  I don't think this is used very often.  It just got a bug fix for a rather serious bug where `--separate-git-dir` can destroy directory contents; this should be in the next Git release.)

---

#### `git rm --cached`

When we use `git rm --cached`, we are telling Git: *Remove this file from the index, but not from the work-tree.*  Now that it's not in Git's index, but is in the work-tree, it is (perhaps again) untracked.  We can commit again, as you do.  Or, we could just `git reset` back now, with `git reset HEAD~1` or `git reset HEAD~` or `git reset HEAD^` (all mean the same thing).  The files we don't want committed, but don't want removed either, aren't in the index, so they won't be removed.

#### `git push`

The `git push` command sends *commits* to some other Git.  Since the index and our work-tree are not commits, they have no effect on the commits we send.  That's why we had to commit these build products: that's the only way to get Git to send them.  (The push operation can work efficiently *because* the commits are uniquely numbered by hash ID, so it's easy for the two Gits to exchange information about which commits they have and which they need—and this also tells the sending Git which *files* the receiver already has, so that the sender need not send copies they already have.)

Having sent to the other Git any commits that they don't have, but will need, a `git push` operation ends with a series of requests, or perhaps commands, to that other Git: *Please set your name ______ (fill in a branch or tag name, for instance) to ______ (fill in a commit hash ID, for instance)*.  Or: *Set your name ______ to ______!* (`git push --force`), or *I think your name ______ has ID ______; if so, set it to ______; tell me if I was right* (`git push --force-with-lease`, which is a command, but conditional).

If they accept the request-or-command, they now have a name for one specific commit.  That commit leads back to some earlier commit(s) through its parent hash IDs, which lead back to still-earlier commits, and so on.  So now the receiving Git has the commits that the sending Git gave it, and has either added new commits—via a polite request, for instance—or maybe has thrown out some commits it used to have via a force-push.

#### Using (or abusing) Git for deployment

Deployment scripts tend to fall into one of two categories.  There are simple and naive ones, implemented as a post-receive or post-update hook:

```
#! /bin/sh

git --work-tree=... checkout -f
```

for instance, and there are fancier ones:

```
#! /bin/sh
while read old new name; do
    ...
done
```

(as a better post-receive hook) where the `...` part figures out which branches, if any, were updated, and deploys only one *particular* branch, and only when it is updated.

All of the real crucial stuff lies in *how* the deployment script works.  Since we can't see yours, we don't know for sure how it works—but if it just runs `git checkout -f`, that uses the receiving Git's index and the `--work-tree` or `GIT_WORK_TREE` set up in that command.  That index therefore tracks the files that Git wrote to that work-tree; moving from commit *X* to commit *Y* will remove any files that are in that Git's index that are there because of commit *X* but that commit *Y* indicates should not be there.

If your deployment script is fancy, it could:

- Build the build-artifacts, which would then be untracked files.  This might have a timing problem, depending on how long they take to build and so on.
- Use *two* commits: extract one with `git checkout` and then do something else—using other Git tools—to add files from some auxiliary commit associated with the commit, that contains (only) the otherwise-untracked files.  This might also have a timing problem, though probably much smaller.

(Note that even the simple method, of checking out one commit, can have a timing problem as it can take a few seconds, or tens of seconds, to do a big checkout.  To shrink this window as small as possible, a smart deployment script might use a directory-swap technique, which has some effect on some of the above possibilities, but not on the proposal below.)

Even if it's not fancy, though, you could have it deploy, not the commit itself, but rather some auxiliary commit associated with the commit.  This auxiliary commit would have *both* the regular files *and* the nominally-untracked files.

That is, you would do exactly the same thing you are doing now, except that instead of deploying `master` or `release` or whatever branch name, you'd use some *other* name that gets updated when the to-be-deployed files are ready to be deployed.

The to-be-deployed branch need not keep any history.  That is, every time you go to build it, you build it as a new orphan branch that contains the to-be-deployed files *plus* the build artifact files.  This requires the kind of force-push you are using now, but means you don't have to "undo the commit later: that just happens automatically.

This does mean you need the deployment script to be at least a little bit smart: it must deploy *only* the special branch name that you use for this particular case, and not deploy the branch you use with normal development.  Or, equivalently, you only *push* the special branch to this one repository, and use a different (non-deployed) repository as your centralized and/or backup site.

Comment: This was very insightful, thank you! I went with the idea of creating a separate orphan branch and adding the build files in that "deployment" branch only. This keeps the "auxiliary" commits relegated to the "deployment" branch (and the rest of the repo "clean"), which works great for me.